# XNA 4.0 for xbox question (confused)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile, xna

At the moment I have visual studio 2010 open, I see XNA Game Studio 4.0 and then I see Xbox 360 Game 4.0 as well as window game (4.0)   I was under the assumption that these were not released yet, or not ready.

1. What happens when I actually use them? am I using XNA 4.0?
2. can I publish to Indie games for xbox(pretty sure I cannot) using XNA 4.0,
3. can I copy the code and use it with 3.1?
4. will I be able to use my code for when they do release xna 4.0 for xbox/window game/anything other than windows phone 7?
5. If I am actually using XNA 4.0 what are the new features? and if there aren't any, what makes this different from XNA 3.1 (other than the phone stuff)

sorry for all the questions just slightly confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What happens when I actually use them? am I using XNA 4.0?

   Yes, you are using 4.0 (the beta, unless you are using the older CTP)
2. can I publish to Indie games for xbox(pretty sure I cannot)

   The beta does not support deployment and testing on the Xbox. I assume this means no publishing to Indie Games.
3. using XNA 4.0, can I copy the code and use it with 3.1?

   No, there are a number of breaking changes in 4.0.
4. will I be able to use my code for when they do release xna 4.0 for xbox/window game/anything other than windows phone 7?

   Yes, the beta can be used with WP7 and Windows, the release will also support Xbox 360.
5. If I am actually using XNA 4.0 what are the new features? and if there aren't any, what makes this different from XNA 3.1 (other than the phone stuff)

   There's been a lot of optimizations and improvements to the API. IMO, the best source to get a grip on all the goodness (and the breaking changes) is [Shawn Hargreaves blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309211619/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/).

Answer (score 1):

These questions can be answered [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/A/4EA52332-C6B1-476E-9938-C4F805146AF5/Release%20Notes%20-%20WPDT%20Beta.htm#tag_xnagame)

Comment: thanks, but so far I know that what I have now is a preview of Xbox Game Development. The wording was kind of weird, mostly "previous preview release of XNA Game Studio 4.0"  I am guessing, I cannot deploy for xbox yet, but once the finished version comes out I will be able to?

Comment: i think that's just to give ppl the "taste" of what's gonna be like to develop with xna 4+ to win phone and such... a bit misguided if that's the case.. but we have history of things like that from them..